# Make a Java JScrollpane only scroll vertically

Tags: java, user-interface, scrollbar, jscrollpane

I would like my entire JFrame to vertically scroll.

I have added the following code, but it only creates a horizontal scrollbar.

```
frame.setContentPane(new JScrollPane(new GradeQuickResource()));
```

I want to do the opposite.  I ONLY want a vertical scrollbar and NO horizontal scrollbar.

I have seen the horizontal policy code, but it doesn't seem to work.  I do not know what to name it.  This code looks something like this:

```
setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

Thanks!

Comment: The code you posted doesn't make sense so its no wonder it doesn't work. You don't have a reference to the scrollpane, so how can you set the horizontal scroll policy? Post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try [this](http://java2everyone.blogspot.com/2008/12/add-scrollbar-to-jframe.html):

```
public class AddScrollBarToJFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JScrollPane scrollBar = new JScrollPane(panel,
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("AddScrollBarToJFrame");
        frame.add(scrollBar);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Also, you can have a look at [*How to use a ScrollBar in both vertical and horizontal direction*](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.swing/how-to-use-a-scrollbar-in-both-vertical-and-horizontal-dire.html).

Comment: This is the link for the first part : http://java2everyone.blogspot.com/2008/12/add-scrollbar-to-jframe.html

Comment: Ah, I see! I added the citation above. For reference, I specified `HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER` to match the question's requirement. +1, BTW.

Comment: For already created panes, these methods can be used: 
 `pane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);` and `pane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);`

Comment: The panel inside the JScrollPane still can grow horizontally on demand. I believe a requirement is to keep it at viewport size.

Answer (score -1):

AFIK:

   `JScrollPane scrollableTa=new JScrollPane(targetComp);
   scrollableTa.setHorizontalScrollBar(null);`

works

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: I guess it depends on used Layouts. Willt try to get full code somwhere from history.