# How Can I make my Scrollpane vertical?

Tags: java

How can I make this scrollpane vertical?

```
public class scrollpane{
    public static void main(String[]args){
    JFrame f=new JFrame();
    JPanel p=new JPanel();
    JLabel l=new JLabel("SCROLL");
    p.add(l);
    f.add(p);
    f.add(new JScrollPane());
    }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a Java JScrollpane only scroll vertically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527487/make-a-java-jscrollpane-only-scroll-vertically)